# How to stop onblur js load loading multiple times?

Tags: javascript

**Here is my js code,i call the function below using onblur method.**

```
function getTotalNew(id)
    {
        //alert(id);
        var con = document.getElementById('con'+id).value;
        con = Number(con);//alert(con);
        var was = document.getElementById('was'+id).value;
        was = Number(was);//alert(was);
        var ttl = document.getElementById('ttl'+id).value;
        ttl = Number(ttl);//alert(ttl);

        var value1 =  (con*ttl);//alert(value1);
        var value2 =  (ttl*con*was)/100;

        var res = value1 + value2; //alert(res);
        document.getElementById('ttl'+id).value = res;
    }
```

I want it to execute it only for once.

But, it's executing whenever I took my mouse out. That's changing my figure abruptly.

How can I make it execute only ONCE?

Comment: Unsubscribe after the first call? use a flag? there are many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try it on onchange event.
Code seems like you want to make calculations on onchange and not on focus out everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flag=1;  

if(flag){
    function getTotalNew(id)
    {
        //alert(id);   
        flag = 0;
        var con = document.getElementById('con'+id).value;
        con = Number(con);//alert(con);
        var was = document.getElementById('was'+id).value;
        was = Number(was);//alert(was);
        var ttl = document.getElementById('ttl'+id).value;
        ttl = Number(ttl);//alert(ttl);

        var value1 =  (con*ttl);//alert(value1);
        var value2 =  (ttl*con*was)/100;

        var res = value1 + value2; //alert(res);
        document.getElementById('ttl'+id).value = res;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Abhishek said you do not want to run the function on Blur, because I will run the function everytime you will move the focus.

You have 2 solution:

1) is to use the onChange instead than onBlur, Infact the onChange will just run the function if the input value has changed, so for example, if you tab though it without making any change it will not run, ( but if you press space it will)

2) use the onKeyDown ( this will run the function every time you type something..). I dont know where your function is used but sometimes it gives a nice dynamic effect to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery **.off** method to keep diable after once it called...

```
function getTotalNew(id)
{
    //alert(id);
    var con = document.getElementById('con'+id).value;
    con = Number(con);//alert(con);
    var was = document.getElementById('was'+id).value;
    was = Number(was);//alert(was);
    var ttl = document.getElementById('ttl'+id).value;
    ttl = Number(ttl);//alert(ttl);

    var value1 =  (con*ttl);//alert(value1);
    var value2 =  (ttl*con*was)/100;

    var res = value1 + value2; //alert(res);
    document.getElementById('ttl'+id).value = res;

    var disId = 'con'+id;
   $("body").off("change", "#"+disId, getTotalNew);
}
```